# QStatemachine to trigger signal: connected slots not called

Tags: qt, qt4, qstatemachine

I want to code a function to show the basic flow of my GUI like if I call that function in a slot it start transitions in states as FileMenu->Open(signal triggered and enables the slot connected to it) and so on. I tried with state machine as:

```
d1->assignProperty(ui->menuFile,"visible",true);

d0->addTransition(d1);

d1->addTransition(ui->actionOpen,SIGNAL(triggered()),d0);

dem->addState(d0);
dem->addState(d1);

dem->setInitialState(d0);
dem->start();
```

File menu is not appearing at the place. Also Signal is not triggered on state transition.  I am new to `QStateMachine`. I am not sure about triggering a signal this way is possible or not. If yes then and what is wrong in my code or is there any better way to do this?

---

Edit: file menu correction :

```
QRect r0 =  this->geometry();
QRect tbar = ui->menuBar->geometry();
QRect r = ui->menuFile->geometry();
r.setCoords(r0.x(),r0.y()+tbar.height(),r0.x()+r.width(),r0.y()+r.height()+tbar.height());

ui->menuFile->setGeometry(r);
ui->menuFile->show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that the code given in the question is within a function, and you want the function to start transitions to show the menu. The function itself is called within a slot.

It is not correct to re-create the state machine in this function, nor is it really necessary for the function to exist.

You should:

1. Create the state machine in the widget/object constructor, and do it only once.
2. Add a `QSignalTransition` to trigger transition to `d1`.

You should also verify that the code otherwise works. Instead of having a state machine in your function, simply show the menu using `ui->menuFile->show()`. This must work before you attempt anything else.

You said that your function is called from a slot. Obviously there's a signal somewhere that triggers that slot. That's the object and the signal that you use to create a `QSignalTransition`.

Comment: Please see the question again.